# Shell Script (.sh file) to read a line and copy specific value to another text file in Android

Tags: android, shell, sh

I'm not so good in english, and I'm new in this

I need a shell script (.sh file) that can read a line and copy the specific value of the line, for example :

I have ***test.txt*** which is containing

`One:       850456`
`Two:        15192`

Inside ***test.txt*** show me 2 lines, i just need the `850456` in the first line, and the number automatically written to another text file. If you can, the another text file is created from this .sh file too

Another problem, if the number is random, there is a way to copy it?

I don't know what is the different between Linux Shell Script and Android Shell Script. But this one, i need to run it from Android

Comment: First, you didn't need to delete your old question. Secondly, please share what you've tried and explain why it has to be a shell script

Comment: Android is based on Linux kernel so there should not be much difference between the two types. Did you try using the commands like `cut`: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/textproc.html ?

Comment: @T.M - shell commands have *nothing* to do with the kernel.  Android has a Linux Kernel, yes, but it has its own userspace, its own shell, and its own collection of utilities.  What is present varies with build - initially very little, today more of what you might expect.

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisStratton. It should have been terminal/shell indeed that is quite similar with a difference that android has fewer commands available than in a full-fledged Linux system. That was what I was trying to convey but yes, it's got nothing to do with the kernel.

Comment: Thanks all of you, i need the command and write it into .sh file, and then put it on flashable zip, i need this to detect MemTotal (first line) from /proc/meminfo and copy only the value, that is what i tried to do. Why i delete my first question, because there is a guy tell me to close it, the other questions have the answers, i realize close is delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is in the format as you have shown:

```
one: 234234234
two: 23423423423
three: 23453453635
four: 2342342342423
```

Then you can use the below command easily without the need for a script

```
cat test.txt | cut -d":" -f2 | sed 's/ //g'
```

The output would be all the numbers from the file above. If you want to save this result to a file then use the below command.

```
cat test.txt | cut -d":" -f2 | sed 's/ //g' > result.txt
```

This will overwrite the file each time with the results.

For first line only you can use something like below

```
head -n 1 test.txt | cut -d":" -f2 | sed 's/ //g' > result.txt
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay i try it, that show me all the number but i just need the first line not the entire of field, this answer my question too but please can you tell me more how to get the first line? just the first line.

Comment: then use this
head -n 1 test.txt | cut -d":" -f2 | sed 's/ //g' > result.txt

I have updated the original answer.

Comment: One more, there is character behind the number like this: `one: 234234234 ab` when i try it, the `ab` is written too, `ab` is not on field 2 right?

Comment: It is because we are separating based on delimiter ":" which means "one" and "234234234 ab". To further divide it you could pipe it to another cut -d"" -f1 command and it will remove the ab part. Here the delimiter is a space or empty space.

Comment: so that is like this `head -n 1 test.txt | cut -d":" -f2 | cut -d"" -f1 | sed 's/ //g' > result.txt`

Comment: May be give me an example file or something so we can do this once?

Comment: I change the sed command like this `head -n 1 test.txt | cut -d":" -f2 | sed 's/[ab ]//g' > result.txt` and the `ab` is gone now, thanks @Junaid you da real mvp

Comment: Glad i could help my friend.